# pySide signal and slots too much code?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I recently started to use new pySide signal and slots and I found that I need a lot of code to handle them. I guess I do something wrong and hope that someone have a better way of doing it.

```
#first I need to declare it at the class level
class UI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    my_signal = QtCore.Signal(str, str)

# next I need to connect it to something in the UI
self.my_signal.connect(self._mySignalHandler)

# then I need the actual handler that does the work:
@QtCore.Slot(str, str)
def _mySignalHandler(self, a, b):
    pass

# and finally I needs an accessor method for it to use it from the outside the UI class:
def mySignalAccessor(self, a, b):
    self.my_signal.emit(a, b)
```

this is a lot of code to do a simple thing. I end up having two methods and a variable all called similarly - really good way to get totally lost in bugs. Do you have a better way do do that?

Answer (score 1):

It's only three lines of code: definition, connection, handler. The accessor is redundant (just give the signal a good, descriptive name and use it like any other built-in signal).

You can probably get rid of the slot decorator, which is not normally required (a signal can be connected to any Python callable, it doesn't have to be a slot).

As for the naming: just pick a format, and stick with it throughout all your projects. For example:

```
    dataReceived = QtCore.Signal(object)

    self.dataReceived.connect(self.handleDataReceived)

    def handleDataReceived(self, data):
```

Boiler-plate code like this can easily be inserted via a template, if your editor has support for that kind of thing.

PS:

In PyQt, there is support for [Connecting Slots By Name](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#connecting-slots-by-name) - I've never used it myself, and I don't know whether it's also supported in PySide, but you might find it useful.

Comment: I don't like exposing internal working of a class to external processes thats why I have the accessor method to hide emission of the signal. Another class shouldn't know that this is a signal and that it has to be emitted.

Comment: @pavel. That is not idiomatic python - it sounds more like java. But in any case, if other classes aren't meant to know about this signal, why are you providing an accessor for it? If you want the signal to be internal to the class, the normal python idiom is to name it with a leading underscore, as you've done with the slot.

Comment: I don't want the signal to be internal. I want to be able to control the interface from the outside without exposing it's internal structure. If my other classes call 'emit' directly and I change the interface to something else that is not using signals and have no 'emit' then a lot of code will have to be updated. With my accessor I control how the interface communicate with the outside world and it provides clean separation.

Comment: @pawel. The whole point of signals and slots is to provide a unified mechanism for loosely-coupled communication between objects. If you have classes that are directly calling the 'emit' of other classes, then that is clearly close-coupling, and therefore *not* a clean separation. The signals and slots mechanism is meant to be used for implementing the Observer Pattern. Objects are supposed to passively *listen* for signals from sources with unknown interfaces. So your so-called signal accessors are an anti-pattern in Qt, because they actively undermine the Observer Pattern.

Comment: thanks ekhumoro. I suspected I was not doing it right. I'm still not sure how to tackle it properly but I will read about it more. I understand that I just need to emit a signal from one class that the other class with user interface is listening to. However this will make both classes depend on pySide/PyQt which is not ideal. That why I provided hooks for signals in the first place. Anyway I need to rethink my approach. Appreciate your comments mate.